# Proving a result of $\text{Re}\left(\frac{1-e^{i(n+1)\theta}}{1-e^{i\theta}}\right)$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

> Show that for $0<\theta<2\pi$:
>   $$\text{Re}\left(\frac{1-e^{i(n+1)\theta}}{1-e^{i\theta}}\right)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\text{sin}\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\theta}{2\text{sin}\frac{\theta}{2}}$$

I am stuck up to this point
\begin{align}
\text{Re}\left(\frac{1-e^{i(n+1)\theta}}{1-e^{i\theta}}\right)&=\frac{1-\text{cos}\theta-\text{cos}(n\theta+\theta)+\text{cos}\theta\text{cos}(n\theta+\theta)}{2-2\text{cos}\theta} \\
&=\frac{1-\text{cos}\theta}{2-2\text{cos}\theta}+\frac{\text{cos}(n\theta+\theta)(\text{cos}\theta-1)}{2-2\text{cos}\theta} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\text{cos}(n\theta+\theta)}{2}
\end{align}

I hint would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite obtain the result of  your first line, but
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{1-e^{i(n+1)\theta}}{1-e^{i\theta}}\right) & =\frac{1-\cos\theta-\cos(n+1)\theta+\cos n\theta }{2(1-\cos\theta)} \\[1ex]
& = \frac12 + \frac{\cos n\theta-\cos(n+1)\theta}{2(1-\cos\theta)}
\end{align}
Now you can use the linearisation/factorisation formulæ:

- $1-\cos\theta=2\sin^2\dfrac\theta2$;
- $\cos p-\cos q=-2\sin\dfrac{p+q}2\,\sin\dfrac{p-q}2$, which yields here
  $$\cos n\theta-\cos(n+1)\theta=-2\sin\dfrac{(2n+1)\theta}2\,\sin\dfrac{-\theta}2=\sin\dfrac{(2n+1)\theta}2\,\sin\dfrac{\theta}2.$$

Comment: Yes, I now see my mistake in the first line.Thanks! The only part I don't understand is how $$1-\cos\theta=2\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}$$ This does not seem obvious to me.

Comment: This comes from one of the duplication formulæ: $\; \cos 2x=1-2\sin^2x$, which can also be read as a linearisation formula: $\;\sin^2x=\dfrac{1-\cos x}2$ (useful for integration).

Comment: Can you prove this by letting $u=2x$? Hence $\sin^2\left(\frac{u}{2}\right)=1-\cos(u)$. Do you know of a link that might further explain it? I'd like to understand it better than what I do now... which is minimal

Comment: You forgot to divide by $2$, since $\color{red}{2}\sin^2\frac u2=1-\cos u$.

Comment: My bad, it's approaching midnight here haha does that argument work though?

Comment: If you mean one replaces $x$ with $\frac θ2$ in the linearisation formula, that's correct.

Comment: Not sure why they keep doing that :/

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

It seems useful refer to   [**Lagrange's trigonometric identities**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Lagrange's_trigonometric_identities)

$$ \sum_{n=1}^N \cos (n\theta)  = -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sin\left(\left(N+\frac{1}{2}\right)\theta\right)}{2\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}$$

observing that for $\theta \neq 2k\pi$

$$\text{Re}\left(\frac{1-e^{i(n+1)\theta}}{1-e^{i\theta}}\right)=\text{Re}(1+e^{i\theta}+\ldots+ e^{in\theta})$$

Comment: Again I don’t think this answer should be downvoted. Everything’s fine.

Comment: @Szeto Thanks for your opinion, I was wondering for some error or mistake! Bye

Comment: @Szeto Since you are so kind, could you please also take a look to that OP which was downvoted also after some correction I've made, for your advice on that, it seems ok to me now. Thanks https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2863348/505767

Answer (score -1):

$$\dfrac{1-e^{2mit}}{1-e^{2it}}=\dfrac{e^{imt}(e^{imt}-e^{imt})}{e^{it}(e^{it}-e^{-it})}$$

$$=e^{i(m-1)t}\cdot\dfrac{2i\sin mt}{2i\sin t}$$

$$=\dfrac{2\sin mt(\cos(m-1)t+i\sin(m-1)t)}{2\sin t}$$

Now $2\sin mt\cos(m-1)t=\sin(2m-1)t+\sin t$

Here $2t=\theta$ and $2mt=(n+1)\theta$